# toLocaleDateString is not defined how to fix?

Tags: javascript, function, date, module, shared-libraries

This is one module that I have put in the views folder for ejs to render and I wish to use it to get date for my site.
This is my code:

```
module.exports = getDate;
function getDate(){
  let today = new Date();
  let options = {weekday: "long", day: "numeric", month: "long"};
  let date = toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
  return date;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you made a simple mistake. (toLocaleDateString) is a property of the date object. That's why you get undefined. The below code is now workable.

```js
function getDate(){
  let today = new Date();
  let options = {weekday: "long", day: "numeric", month: "long"};
  let date = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
  return date;
}
```

Comment: Haha, I'm so embarassed.

Comment: It's ok. It's not a big deal.